# nodeJS function documentation syntax

Tags: node.js

I'm slightly confused by the nodeJS documentation.

For instance, looking at the [assert module](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) I instantly see

```
assert(value[, message])
```

how exactly do I read this? I understand assert is a function that takes a parameter called value, but what exactly does [, message] mean? Does it mean message is an array? Why does the comma not come before the initial opening bracket?

Answer (score 1):

The example you provide simply means that the parameter "message" is optional. The documentation states:

> If value is not truthy, an AssertionError is thrown with a message property set equal to the value of the message parameter. If the message parameter is undefined, a default error message is assigned.

Comment: Oh that makes. So in an example like assert.doesNotThrow(block[, error][, message]) it just means error and message are both optional?

Comment: Yes. Both parameters "error" and "message" are optional when using the doesNotThrow assertion.

Comment: Where can I find documentation about this?